# Is HandBrake tune -still image applicable to videos with minimal movement?

Tags: encoding, handbrake

I have some educational videos that are mostly PowerPoint slides and a teacher sitting in a chair talking.

Is the -still image tune applicable for videos like that? I would like to make them as small as possible.

Comment: Ironically, I find that with no tune specified, I get smaller sizes, all else being equal, for slideshow videos. Although since you do have some live video in your frame, I would suggest skipping the tune.

Comment: @Mulvya Make it a answer then!

Answer (score 1):

My experience with handbrake mirrors [Mulvya`s comment](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20650/is-handbrake-tune-still-image-applicable-to-videos-with-minimal-movement#comment29835_20650)

I also get smaller file sizes with X264 Tune set to <kbd>None</kbd> on the Video Tab.